# How to recieve print data on Linux from a CN36 cable?

Tags: linux, usb, printer, parallel-port

I have a HP 200LX palmtop computer with some proprietary software on it. The palmtop communicates with a printer with a cable from an proprietary 8-pin HP connector (on the palmtop) to a standard CN36 printer parallel connector (on the printer). Recently, the palmtop stopped printing, and I'd like to try and debug it.

I've bought a `USB -> CN36 (male)` adapter, and used this to connect my laptop to the printer. I did get it to print a text file, so I suspect the issue is with the palmtop instead.

I also bought a `CN36 (female) -> DB25 (male)` and `DB25 (female) -> USB` adapter. There are no `CN36 (female) -> USB` adapters that I could find. The setup looks like this:

```
(HP LX200)  8-pin Connector  -->  CN36  -->  DB25  -->  USB  (Laptop)
```

When I plug the USB cable into my laptop, it is recognized as a printer cable. Here is the dmesg output:

```
[  283.831160] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  283.973070] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7584, bcdDevice= 2.64
[  283.973084] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  283.973089] usb 1-3: Product: USB Print
[  284.010142] usblp 1-3:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 7 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x1A86 pid 0x7584
```

And a character device is created at `/dev/usb/lp1`. However, when I send a print command from the palmtop, I don't get any output from `lp1` (checking with `cat /dev/usb/lp1`).

Is there any way for me to monitor the raw data coming from the cable? Similar to dumping the raw data from a serial connection on e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Do I need to write my own driver? Or would it be easier to get a CN36 breakout board and monitor the pins themselves?

Model information for adapters:

`USB -> CN36 (Male)`: SinLoon ‎SL2020040701

`USB -> DB25 (Female)`: SABRENT ‎B00IDUD61Y

`DB25 (Female) -> CN36 (Male)`: KENTEK KT-DB25M-CN36F-ADA

Comment: What you call "*`USB -> CN36 (male)` connector*" and "*`DB25 (female) -> USB` connector*" need better descriptions by you. Those are (probably) not mere "*connectors*", but are "adapters" that have active electronics, and are USB devices that require host drivers. "*And a block device is created at `/dev/usb/lp1`*" - A *block* device?!!! I would expect a *character* device. BTW this is really an XY problem. You're ignoring the likeliest issue: a bad palmtop *cable*.

Comment: I suspect that your cable is intended to be used the other way around: for output rather than input, i.e. to drive a parallel printer from a USB port. As @sawdust points out, this is an adapter, not just a cable. Do you have a model number for the cable?

Comment: If you're correct, I imagine it'll be the same for any commercial product which I could use to connect my parallel cable to my laptop. I'll find a breakout board and hook it up to a raspberry pi instead. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW, it might be worth asking this question on the [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) site. I mean that HP 200LX definitely qualifies as a “retrocomputing” device.

Answer (score 1):

Because the cable has to translate from DB-25 (parallel) to USB (serial), it isn't only a connector, but an adapter with active electronics. Because this product was designed to connect a computer to a parallel printer, and not the other way around, it's unlikely to work for the purpose I need it for.

After doing some more research online, there seems to be a product, the [Retro-Printer](https://www.retroprinter.com/) which is designed for my use case. However, given the price point, it will be much cheaper to attempt to recreate this module myself, so this will be my next step.